# I want to update the glibc version from 2.17-222.el7.x86_64 to 2.17-260.el7

Tags: centos, upgrade, glibc

I want to update the glibc version from 2.17-222.el7.x86_64 to  2.17-260.el7. Will there be any effect ? IS 2.17-260.el7 compatible to centos 7.2 as all my machines are in centos 7.2 only.

Comment: Do you want to update *only* glibc? If so, why? And why do you want to update glibc, if you don’t know whether it will have any effect?

Comment: Yes, there will be. Some of your files get delete then replaced by new files. Some of your files with be writte to.

Comment: @Stephen-I want to update both glibc and nss-pem packages as the current version i.e. (2.17-222.el7.x86_64) shows vulnerable when Qualsys ran and the version( 2.17-260.el7) is not supported in centos 7.2 as its included from centos 7.4.

Comment: CentOS 7.2 isn’t supported at all, and once you have updated glibc, you aren’t running 7.2 anymore anyway.

Comment: Thanks everyone!...That means glibc 2.17-260.el7 does not support at all in CentOs7.2 ? and the approach would be to upgrade CentOS version to 7.4 ?

Comment: Neither 7.2 nor 7.4 are supported at all, so do what you want, it’s your problem now.

Answer (score 3):

You could certainly try, however you will need to pull in many dependencies along side glibc. Also, any reason why you’d be staying at CentOS 7.2 would most likely be lost, since you’d be running the base OS of a much newer version with parts and pieces of 7.2.

Run “yum update glibc” and see what changes.

You might want to just consider running the only supported version of a CentOS 7 that there is — the one with all the updates.  Otherwise you are running an OS that you support entirely, and if it breaks (and it will) the only person who can fix it will be you.